# Definite article before a (mathematical) topic's name

Tags: mathematics, definite-article

I will leap in with two translations by [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator):

**First translation**

Input:

> Linear regression is a powerful tool.

Output:

> Die lineare Regression ist ein leistungsfähiges Instrument.

**Second translation**

Input:

> Modular arithmetic is crucial to cryptography.

Output:

> Die modulare Arithmetik ist für die Kryptographie von entscheidender Bedeutung.

**Question**

In both cases, the definite article was added – *die Lineare Regression*, rather than merely *lineare Regression*. **How crucial is this definite article?** In English one would never use the definite article in this way, but rather only if one were referring to a specific instance and not to the topic itself, for example:

> The study was flawed because the linear regression did not control for age.

Even here I would be tempted to write *the linear regression model* and not just *the linear regression*.

The two examples are about mathematical topics. I don't know how important that is here.

Comment: This is kind of difficult. Based on "Sprachgefühl" I would not use the definite article in the first example. Looking at [the rules](https://dict.leo.org/grammatik/deutsch/Wort/Artikel/Gebrauch/Ohne.xml?lang=de#id=1.6.3.3.b), I think that is because "Regression" is an abstract noun and a procedure/process. In the second example I would tend to use the article. I'm not writing an answer because I'm not 100 % sure regarding which rules apply. It also could depend on context.

Comment: In general German does tend to use articles where English doesn't, especially with abstract nouns. There are some guidelines, but it seems impossible to completely reduce differences to a small number of simple rules. You just have to develop a kind of intuition for it. A simpler example is *Liebe*/"love"; it rarely gets an article in English, but in German it seems about 50/50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note this is not a must.

> Lineare Regression ist ein wichtiges Verfahren in der Statistik

is just about as correct and common as

> Die lineare Regression ist ein wichtiges Verfahren in der Statistik

This is a bit hard to explain:

Maybe the easiest is

If you can rephrase the sentence to

> *Die Wissenschaft* (or *das Verfahren*) der ...

you *can* put a definite article.

(That is, you are referring to the "science" or abstract method).

This is not limited to Mathematics, but can be observed in any science:

> Das Galvanisieren ist ein Verfahren zur Oberflächenbeschichtung von Metallen.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what is happening here is that [English does not tend to use definite articles before abstract nouns referring to general concepts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/196176/article-in-front-of-abstract-noun). This is an unusual feature of English. It is not necessarily true of other languages that have definite articles.

In German, these sentences are fine both with and without a definite article. This is not specific to mathematical or even scientific topics. Another example is the name of ideologies. In English, you can only say someone *supports democracy* (the definite article would not sound good here), but in German, you can say someone *unterstützt die Demokratie* and I think this usually sounds better than without the definite article.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need the article because of the adjective:

Regression is female in German, so it's "linear**e** Regression".

For example:

Schöne**s** Zimmer
Schön**e** Wohnung
Schöne**r** Wolkenkratzer

The general topic is the "Nullartikel"

https://www.das-akademie.de/adjektivdeklination-leicht-erklaert/

> Adjektivdeklination ohne Artikel (Nullartikel)
>
> Wenn vor dem Nomen kein Artikel steht, nennt man das Nullartikel. Hier
> muss das Adjektiv den Kasus signalisieren. Die Endung des bestimmten
> Artikels (der, die, das…) muss also an das Ende des Adjektivs. Die
> einzige Ausnahme ist der Genitiv maskulin und neutrum. Das -s am Ende
> des Nomens markiert bereits den Kasus, deshalb bekommt das Adjektiv
> hier die schwache Endung -en.
>
> Ein altes Auto steht in der großen Garage. Neue Schuhe sind oft teuer.
> Der alte Mann trinkt gerne kaltes Bier. Der kleine Junge mag schnelle
> Autos.
>
> Ich bade in kaltem Wasser.

You also do not have to put an article before "Eigennamen", "Lineare Regression" is a "Eigenname".

Comment: I don't think this answer targets the core of the question. It's not about the grammatical concept but the (nuances of) usage..

Comment: @choXer I think it does. The question was how cucial is the usage of the article, it's not at all.